# Adding and deleting markers after initialization function in Google Map v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

I want to show markers on a map. These have to  to move a new location.

Since I could not figure out moving a marker, I decided to delete the existing marker and create a new one instead.

But the markers don't get deleted. instead a new marker with the same label keeps appearing in the new location.

```
  var markers = [];     


function addMarker(lat, lon, id, label, speed, course, temp) {

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        name:id,
        id:id,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),     
        draggable: true,
        optimized:false,
        map: map,
        labelContent: label,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        labelClass: "labels",  
        labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
    });

    if(temp!=""){
        temptext = "<br />Temprature "+ temp;
    }  else{
        temptext =" ";
    }



    markers[id]=marker;
    console.log(markers);
    iw[id] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<b>"+label+"</b><br />Speed:"+speed+" KM/h "+ "<br />heading "+ course + temptext+"<br />["+id+"]",       
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { iw[id]
        .open(map, marker); });

}


   function clearMarker(id){

    if(typeof markers[id] == 'object'){

        console.log("key exists" +id);  
        delmarker = markers[id]
        delmarker.setMap(null);
         parent.markers.splice(id, 1)  ;
         //console.log(markers);     
    }      else{
        console.log(id+ "key does not exist" );      
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `markers` is an array, since you declare it as such at the top, yet later you're using the `key in object` method to check if something is in that array? Are you sure it should'nt be `if(typeof markers[id] == 'object'){ ... }`

Comment: @adeneo I did change it as you suggested. But the marker still does not get deleted.